# proof of "if union of nonempty subset of natural number set is itself, then it is natural number set"

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

This is a exercise problem in Pinter set theory textbook.
Let $A$ be a nonempty subset of $\omega$ (The natural number set). Prove that if $\cup A = A$, then $A = \omega$

Intuitively I can imagine that $A$ must be infinite, but I am not sure how to show that this must be equal to $\omega$, because I haven't learn the concept of 'infinite' yet, Probably I should use mathematical induction, but it is not clear for me.

How should I deal with this?

Comment: I don't understand $\cup A$, what does it means ?  If I take $A=\{1\}$ any non empty subset of $A$ is $A$ and so is the union. On the other hand if I consider A=even numbers, then it verifies also your property without being all naturals. Your problem is quite unclear.

Comment: In my reference, a natural number is defined to be a set such as n={0,1,...,n-1}

Comment: Can you give a definition of $\cup A$ please.

Comment: if A is a set of sets, cup A is the union of all the sets in A

Comment: @zwim. $\cup A=\{x:\exists B\in A\;(x\in B)\}$..... A handy abbreviation for $\cup_{B\in A}B.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks, florence's answer makes sense now, I've never seen this abbreviation before, so I was wondering.

Comment: @zwim. It's used a lot .Any time you need to talk about the common union of a family $F$ of sets, you just say $\cup F.$ You don't need to assume some sort of "index" of the members of $F$. Even when you have an index set $J,$  e.g.$ F=\{G_j:j\in J\} ,$  you can still just write $\cup F$ for $\cup_{j\in J}G_j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that $A$ must be unbounded above, for if $n=\max A$, then $n\notin \bigcup A$ (this uses the fact that every nonempty bounded above subset of $\omega$ has a maximum). Now let $n\in \omega$. Since $A$ is unbounded above, there exists $m\in A$ such that $m>n$. Then $n\in m$, and so $n\in \bigcup A = A$. Thus, $A = \omega$.

Here's a proof using induction. $A$ is nonempty, so let $x\in A$. Then $0\in x$ (or $0=x$, in which case, $0\in A$), and so $0\in \bigcup A = A$. Further, suppose $n\in A$. Then $n\in \bigcup A$, and so $n\in m$ for some $m\in A$. If $m=n+1$, then we're done. Otherwise, $n+1\in m$, and so $n+1\in \bigcup A = A$.